# Setting of binfmt_misc is gone after rebooting

Tags: linux, linker, interpreter, loader

I set the binfmt_misc for i386 binaries on a x64 machine to use a customized loader (qemu-i386-static) to load 32-bit binaries.

I followed the procedure here:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.rst

Basically, it is one line command:

```
echo ':qemu-i386:M::\x7fELF\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00:\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xff\xff\xff:/usr/bin/qemu-i386-static:' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

After doing this, I can see the new entry of `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-i386` and it works for loading 32-bit binaries.

However, after rebooting the machine, this entry is missing. I need to redo the procedure.

How to keep it persistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have systemd you can use systemd-binfmt service. See man systemd-binfmt for help.

In my Ubuntu 18.04 the files for systemd-binfmt service are located in `/etc/binfmt.d/` folder. So try to do this:

```
sudo echo ':qemu-i386:M::\x7fELF\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00:\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xff\xff\xff:/usr/bin/qemu-i386-static:' > /etc/binfmt.d/qemu.conf
```